# how to avoid overlapping sounds in libGdx?

Tags: android, audio, libgdx

hi I am using the sound class for my music so it will loop correctly (as advised here [Libgdx: Lags in soundtrack looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230314/libgdx-lags-in-soundtrack-looping)) but when i close the app(it stills runs in the background) and open it again the sound starts to play over the previous sound, how can i avoid this?

This is my current music handler class

```
public class MusicHandler {
    private Sound bgMusic;

    public MusicHandler(Sound backgroundMusic){
           bgMusic = backgroundMusic;
    }

    public void update(boolean play){
        if(play){
           bgMusic.loop();
        }
        else{
            bgMusic.pause();
        }
    }

    public void dispose(){
        bgMusic.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: music gives you isplaying() interface but I don't think any interface of that sort is there with sound.

Comment: Since interface does give an option of getting length and isPlaying, the only option IMO is while writing the application store the mp3 length and then keep a track of when the sound was played, `if((now-played_time_stamp)> length_of_sound )` play again

Comment: When you play or loop a sound it will return an id.You could on resume stop the last id.