# Libgdx playing music in a loop

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to loop a song duting the game, the song runs good but when it should loop it make a stop for a second and loop , in the file itself it doesn't have thid secod pause
I use ogg file instead of mp3

any ideas?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question, you can check this issue:[ "Libgdx: Lags in soundtrack looping"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230314/libgdx-lags-in-soundtrack-looping)

Answer (score 0):

There is a detail and accepted answer to this question in another post, For more information, I refer you to this link [Libgdx: Lags in soundtrack looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230314/libgdx-lags-in-soundtrack-looping)

By the way if you are playing loop musics, It's good to use WAV format instead of MP3 or OGG. WAV formats are big to store but is easier to decode and use in memory.

Otherwise MP3 is preferred.